# Unable to create json using gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have to make dynamic hashes, so the class example won't work since the class variables are static. I am sending in a hashmap object to toJson but it isn't working. Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: The Gson source code does register an adapter for `Map` type objects (http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn-history/r513/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/DefaultTypeAdapters.java), you're *sure* that `Gson.toJson(yourHashMap)` doesn't work?

Comment: When my hashmap is only initialized it seems to work, but actually adding values to it gives me Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: condition failed: false

Comment: @tipu: Weird. Are your keys or values types that Gson doesn't understand?

Comment: Crowder, this is my hashmap declaration:

public HashMap<String, Integer> word = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

Comment: @tipu: So...safe to say that Gson already knows how to handle those. :-) Sorry, no idea!

Comment: you should post your code and be more precise and what do you mean by "isn't working"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't work out the Gson problem, you might look at Crockford's [JSON classes for Java](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/package-summary.html), they deal with this [exact use case](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.util.Map). Not an answer for the Gson issue, though; just an end-run.